# Java heapsort program error during runtime

Tags: java, heapsort

My code is working during compilation but the runtime error points to an if condition in my `MaxHeapify` function. I marked it out. Any help would be simply lovely, and would make me stop banging my head against the wall.

```
public class HeapSort {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int A[] = {-100, 1, 2, 5, 7, 2, 9};
        Heapsort(A);
        //System.out.println(A.length);
        for (int x = 1; x < A.length; x++) {
            System.out.println(A[x] + " ");
        }
    }

    public static void Build_MAX_heap(int A[]) {
        int n = A.length;
        for (int i = n / 2; i >= 1; i--) {
            MAX_heapify(A, i);
        }
    }

    public static void MAX_heapify(int A[], int i) {
        int heapsize = A.length;
        int l = 2 * i;
        int r = 2 * i + 1;
        //find the largest of A[i].A[l],A[r]
        int largest = i;
        if (A[l] > A[largest]) {
            largest = l;
            if (A[l] > A[largest] && l <= heapsize) {
                largest = l;
            }
            if (A[r] > A[largest] && r <= heapsize) {     //runtime error here
                largest = r;
            }
            if (largest != i) {
                int temp = A[i];
                A[i] = A[largest];
                A[largest] = temp;
                MAX_heapify(A, largest);
            }
        }
    }

    public static void Heapsort(int A[]) {

        Build_MAX_heap(A);
        int heapsize = A.length;
        for (int last = heapsize; last >= 2; last--) {   
            int temp = A[1];
            A[1] = A[last];
            A[last] = temp;
            heapsize--;
            MAX_heapify(A,1);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Well, what is the error??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Variable `r` is set to:

```
int r = 2 * i + 1;
```

In first case of loop:

```
for (int i = n / 2; i >= 1; i--) {
    MAX_heapify(A, i);
}
```

`i` is `n/2`

so to function is passed:

```
MAX_heapify(A,n/2);
```

and `r` is `2 * (n/2) + 1` which is `n+1`

when you want to do this line

```
if (A[r] > A[largest] && r <= heapsize) {
```

then `A[r]` is `A[n+1]=A[A.length+1]` - this causes `IndexOutOfBoundsException`

Comment: Thank you guys for all your help!

Answer (score 1):

You're doing you bounds checking for `r` (and `l`, too, in the previous statement) *after* checking the element at index `r`. If r is out of bounds, the first half of the expression will throw an exception, and never make it to the bounds check.

Your if statements should be structured

```
if (r < heapsize && A[r] > A[largest]) ...
```

so that you know you're in bounds before you start trying to access your array. In addition, since arrays are zero-indexed, the index of `heapsize` isn't valid, so `r` needs to be less than, not less than or equal to.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that your are checking A[r] before checking if r is out of range 
so i would try to modify the code this way

```
 public class HeapSort {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    int A[] = {-100, 1, 2, 5, 7, 2, 9};
    Heapsort(A);
    //System.out.println(A.length);
    for (int x = 1; x < A.length; x++) {
        System.out.println(A[x] + " ");
    }
}

public static void Build_MAX_heap(int A[]) {
    int n = A.length;
    for (int i = n / 2; i >= 1; i--) {
        MAX_heapify(A, i);
    }
}

public static void MAX_heapify(int A[], int i) {
    int heapsize = A.length;
    int l = 2 * i;
    int r = 2 * i + 1;
    //find the largest of A[i].A[l],A[r]
    int largest = i;
    if (A[l] > A[largest]) {
        largest = l;
        if (A[l] > A[largest] && l <= heapsize) {
            largest = l;
        }
        if (r<=heapsize && A[r] > A[largest]) {     //modification here
            largest = r;
        }
        if (largest != i) {
            int temp = A[i];
            A[i] = A[largest];
            A[largest] = temp;
            MAX_heapify(A, largest);
        }
    }
}

public static void Heapsort(int A[]) {

    Build_MAX_heap(A);
    int heapsize = A.length;
    for (int last = heapsize; last >= 2; last--) {   
        int temp = A[1];
        A[1] = A[last];
        A[last] = temp;
        heapsize--;
        MAX_heapify(A,1);
    }
}

}
```